# DrawParentBackground / DrawThemeParentBackground on a top level form

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+, gdi

Consider the following example. This was done by setting the `TransparencyKey` property:

```
public Form()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.BackColor = Color.Fuscia;
    this.TransparencyKey = this.BackColor;
}
```

[image: Example form]

What I actually want to be able to do is similar to the behavior of the [DrawThemeParentBackground](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773306%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function (conveniently wrapped up in .NET as [DrawParentBackground](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.buttonrenderer.drawparentbackground%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), however this does not seem to work for top level forms (only controls).

I have tried to use the `TransparencyKey` behavior along with overriding the `OnPaint` method:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, 255, 0, 0)), this.ClientRectangle);
}
```

**Result:**

[image: Example]

**Question:**

How can I draw the content underneath the ClientRectangle of a top level form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the effect you want?

[image]

If so, you can use two different forms. You do the drawing in the second one.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form2 form2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BackColor = Color.White;
        this.TransparencyKey = Color.White;
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        this.Location = new Point(200, 200);
        form2 = new Form2();
        form2.StartPosition = this.StartPosition;
        form2.Location = this.Location;
        form2.Show();

        this.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(Form1_FormClosed);
        this.LocationChanged += new EventHandler(Form1_LocationChanged);
        this.SizeChanged += new EventHandler(Form1_SizeChanged);
    }

    void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        form2.Close();
    }

    void Form1_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form2.Location = this.Location;
    }

    void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form2.Size = this.Size;
    }
}
```

and

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ShowInTaskbar = false;
        this.Opacity = 0.8;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0)), this.ClientRectangle);
    }
}
```